# Error in server build

Tags: codenameone, parse4cn1

Good day all, I have just followed the steps given in order to implement push notifications using the parse4cn1 lib. On sending an android build I received this error build, I really dont know what next to do as I followed the instructions carefully. Any help will be appreciated. Below is a link leading to the error.txt file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByIex_y9vYt5UGpfNS1YdkdLZ0k

Comment: What's in your `codenameone_settings.properties` file?

Comment: I don't know what that means sir...could it be where I set build hints??

Comment: Yes, your build hints, switch to `Files` tab on your project and you will find `codenameone_settings.properties` file.

Comment: ok..thanks ,below is a link pointing to the text in the codenameone_settings.properties file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByIex_y9vYt5T2Z4WnAtU2NrY0k

Answer (score 0):

The package name you used in build hint `android.xapplication_attr` should map to your applications package name and not the parse package name.